# positive lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

Use lookaheads to match a string that is greater than 5 characters long and have two consecutive digits.

I know the solution should be

```
/(?=\w{6,})(?=\D*\d{2})/
```

But why the second element is

```
(?=\D*\d{2})
```

Instead of

```
(?=\d{2})
```

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: You want to match 2 consecutive digits `\d{2}`. They can be anywhere in the string, so you assert what is on the right is 0+ times not a digit `\D*` and then 2 digits.

Comment: There can be something before the digits.

Comment: The description and the regex do not correspond. For instance: why `\w`? There is no rule about that in your description. It would also not match `1abc23`. Bit difficult to answer when the premise is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `/(?=\w{6,})(?=\D*\d{2})/` does not ensure there will be a match in a string with 2 consecutive digits.

Check this demo:

```js
var reg = /(?=\w{6,})(?=\D*\d{2})/;
console.log(reg.test("Matches are found 12."))
console.log(reg.test("Matches are not found 1 here 12."))
```

This happens because `\D*` only matches any non-digit chars, and once the `\w{6,}` matches, `(?=\D*\d{2})` wants to find the two digits after any 0+ digits, but it is not the case in the string.

So, **`(?=\w{6,})(?=\D*\d{2})` matches a location in the string that is immediately followed with 6 or more word chars and any 0+ non-digit chars followed with 2 digits**.

The correct regex to validate if a string contains 6 or more word chars *and* two consecutive digits anywhere in the string is

```
var reg = /^(?=.*\w{6,})(?=.*\d{2})/;
```

Or, to support multiline strings:

```
var reg = /^(?=[^]*\w{6,})(?=[^]*\d{2})/;
```

where `[^]` matches any char. Also, `[^]` can be replaced with `[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` or `[\w\W]`.

And **to match a string that is greater than 5 characters long and have two consecutive digits** you may use

```
var reg = /^(?=.*\d{2}).{5,}$/
var reg = /^(?=[\s\S]*\d{2})[\s\S]{5,}$/
```

where

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[\s\S]*\d{2})` - there must be two digits anywhere after 0+ chars to the right of the current location
- `[\s\S]{5,}` - five or more chars
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

The lookahead has to allow the 2 digits anywhere in the input. If you used just `(?=\d{2})` then the 2 digits would have to be at the beginning.

You could also use `(?=.*\d{2})`. The point is that `\d{2}` has to be preceded by something that can match the rest of the input before the digits.